# Things to be aware of when designing a custom equatorial fork mount

Tags: telescope

I'm still relatively new to amateur astronomy, and I would like to get into astrophotography. I've looked at different equatorial mounts, and I think I like the benefits of fork mounts. I'd like to design one that can be adjusted to fit a few different scopes and probably a camera with large lens. The way I would do this is by making various adapters, and possibly allowing the fork width to be changed.

As I have never done this before, what issues should I expect to encounter, especially with regard to tracking accuracy?

Comment: I'd recommend a fixed-width fork for strength and stability, with as many inner-adapters as needed for smaller telescopes.